# EE 3.5.17 Infinite redirect (302) loop when logging into CP

Tags: control-panel, ee3, login

I am new to the EE community. I came across a situation today that myself and my co-workers could not figure out. I am running a site locally on docker containers (Ubuntu, PHP 5.4, Apache 2.2.22, MYSQL 5.5.44). The site was on EE 2.6.1 and I followed the guide to upgrade it to EE 3.5.17. The upgrade seemed to go through. I can see the frontend of my site; however, when I try to login to the CP, I get an infinite redirect (302) loop until Apache hits its URI size limit.

The network tab on my browser looks like

http://site.test/asdfjkl.php
302 redirect to
http://site.test/asdfjkl.php?/cp/login&return=
302 redirect to 
http://site.test/asdfjkl.php?/cp/login&return=DHDHDHD
302 redirect to 
http://site.test/asdfjkl.php?/cp/login&return=DHDHDHDFTFTFTFTF
302 redirect to 
http://site.test/asdfjkl.php?/cp/login&return=DHDHDHDFTFTFTFTFRURURURU

I removed my .htaccess file completely to see if it was causing the issue and I got the same results when trying to login to the CP.

I tracked down where the redirects were happening in the EE code.

When booting a CP, system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php (line 188) is called. It tries to create a new class:

$controller = new $class;

When that class is initiated, run_cp() in system/ee/legacy/libraries/Core.php (line 471) is called. It checks to see if a Admin session exists, it does not, so it redirects:

ee()->functions->redirect(BASE.AMP.'C=login'.$return_url);

It seems that this function is called over and over again until Apache stops it because the length of the URI.

I really appreciate any advice you might have to give. Thanks!

Note:
site.test -> EE 3.5.17 site running locally on docker container
asdfjkl.php -> fake name for my admin.php file
DHDHDHDFTFTFTFTFRURURURU -> fake string

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happened because (1) I did not have addon.setup.php for a custom module or (2) I had uninstalled a module that I actually needed before performing the upgrade from EE2 to EE3. I walked through the upgrade again and it worked the second time around when I had corrected the two issues above. Hope this helps someone else at some point.